# Do models learn a test set after multiple predictions upon it?

Tags: machine-learning

In machine learning, when we train a model, such as

```
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=5, ngram_range=(1,2)).fit(X_train)

X_train_vectorized = vect.transform(X_train)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train_vectorized, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(vect.transform(X_test))
```

and make predictions with a test set, does our model learn the test set after multiple predictions are made?

Answer (score 2):

TL/DR: **No.**

---

The concept of prediction, here applied by your `predict` method, is to *just try out the model on the test set*. It does not imply any kind of *adaptation* to such set, thus your model doesn't directly learn anything from it.

You can generalize that to any other framework or discussion in data science as a whole - *training* and *fitting* are tasks performed on the train set, and they imply adapting to it, and actually learning its patterns. Predicting does not.